# Alternative to recursion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, infinite-recursion

I'm starting to learn Python. Right now I'm creating a CLI that allows to create, view or delete contacts stored in a SQLite 3 DB. The problem is that everytime I finish a task  I call the main function again so a user can do other things. The code looks like this:

```
def main(self):
    print("What operation would you like to perform: Display contacts (1), add a new one (2), or remove one  (3)?")
    option = int(input())
    try:
        if option == 1:
            self.display()
            self.main()
        elif option == 2:
            self.new()
            self.main()
        elif option == 3:
            self.delete()
            self.main()
    except TypeError:
        print("Please introduce a valid option")
        sys.exit()
```

I'm pretty sure that successive calls of a function decrease its performance and I think there is a limit of how many times you can call a recursive function, so how should I call the main method again?

Comment: Use a loop to repeat all the contents of `main` while `option == 1`

Comment: Your `except` clause will never be hit.  Did you intend for the `option = int(input())` line to be inside the `try`?  You know, you don't really need to incur the cost of exceptions there.  You can say `if option == '1':` and skip the conversion to integer.

Answer (score 1):

You're right about recursive calls. They can be good, but iteration is often better than recursion.

There's a lot that you can do to do infinite programm, but the easiest way, for cli, is to put all your function in a loop.

This is kinda ugly, but that should work without you having to call for main() everytime.

```
def main(self):
    again=True
    while again:
        print("What operation would you like to perform: Quit(0) Display contacts (1), add a new one (2), or remove one  (3)?")
        option = int(input())
        if option == 0:
            again=False
        if option == 1:
            self.display()
            self.main()
        elif option == 2:
            self.new()
            self.main()
        elif option == 3:
            self.delete()
            self.main()
        else:
            print("Please introduce a valid option")
```

With that said, you still have to call main()

Comment: `continue` is a keyword and can't be used as variable name or expression.

Comment: `continue=True` is a syntax error, `continue` is a keyword

Comment: You still have the `continue` keyword in your code, at `continue=False`

Answer (score -1):

You can use argument libraries like [getopt](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getopt.html) or [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse)

The main goal here is manage the options inside a loop and call it all at once. Ex:

$ python3 ./script.py -123

Answer (score -2):

In python there is no such thing as **"main function"** or **"main method"**.
If you want, you can read about [constructors](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/constructors-in-python/), [call operations](http://pythonlearn.ru/perezagruzka-operatorov-python/operaciya-vyzova-__call__-v-python/) and etc.
So, if I understood correctly - you want to recursive call "main" method.

---

You can count occurrences in this method like this:
`def main(self, count= <your number>):`
And after this, if you want to call this recursive, create loop or just sum "count":

```py
<some code here>
if count == <your number>:
    return
else:
    count += 5
self.main(count)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it sounds like the OP is asking *exactly the opposite*, i.e. how *not to use recursion here*